# how to solve AttributeError: <asgiref.local.Local object at 0x7f6bdcb3a6d0> object has no attribute 'request' django 4.1 python3.11

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.11, asgi, django-4.1

when I run the server: python manage.py runserver
it runs normaly .. but when I refresh in the browser on 127.0.0.1:8000
the error comes

I try to on other page it comes the same error

`AttributeError: <asgiref.local.Local object at 0x7f9ba65c1f50> object has no attribute 'request'`

Comment: where is the code ?